# Why am I still able to use unsigned drivers without pressing F8 disable driver signature enforcement?

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, dism, slipstream

I am booted into windows 7 with test signing off and without enabling 'disable driver signature enforcement'

[image]

These drivers are working fine and I'm not sure why.

Initially, when I installed windows 7 on this system a few days ago, and prior to that slipstreamed amdrxhci and amdrhub3 using dism into install.wim and boot.wim, the keyboard and mouse worked for the setup without having to disable driver signature enforcement, but when the setup completed, you had to use F8 and enable disable driver signature enforcement in order for the USB ports to work. You had to do this every time that the system booted.

At some random point after installing hotfixes to get windows update working, and then around 200 updates from windows update, the USB ports just worked without having to do this, and I'm not sure why.

I later manually installed the driver for the USB 3.2 port xHCI controller and root hub drivers in device manager (amdxhc31, amdhub3), and it installed it fine, and I dont need to enable disable driver signature enforcement on every boot.

Why is this?

I found a similar question on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569189/how-did-this-unsigned-driver-get-installed-on-windows-7-64-bit), but none of the answers answer the question.

And no, I've checked the BCD and I haven't got integrity checks disabled or testsigning on (but that's irrelevant because the drivers aren't even signed)

Comment: How do you know that these unsigned drivers were really used by Windows?

Comment: @harrymc because they're the drivers that are being used when you click on the xhci controller and USB hubs in device manager, and I installed them on device manager using a USB where I had the drivers. It says the driver is unsigned when you go on driver details on device manager